# How to expand menu width in desktop?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My drop down menu is fine in mobile, but on desktop won't expand past the word `home`or menu bars. I'd like it to stretch full page width when clicked. How do I do this please?

I tried css:

```
@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768) 
{#menu {width: 100%! Important;}}
```

It didn't budge even a millimetre.

Html:

```
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div><div 
class="module-group right"><div class="module left"><div 
class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul 
id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-1496" 
class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item 
page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu-item- 
has-children menu-item-1496 dropdown active"><a 
title="Home" href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home </a>. 
<span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-          
toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></span><ul role="menu" class=" 
dropdown-menu"><li id="menu-item-1502" class="fa fa- 
user menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item- 
object-page menu-item-1502"><a title="Create Adsler 
Account" href="https://adsler.co.uk/create- 
account/">Create Adsler Account</a></li><li id="menu- 
item-1499" class="fa fa-envelope menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item- 
1499"><a title="Post
```

Comment: Please provide a working example of your code. It's very hard to follow how the class names in the html affect what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please see desktop view (chrome, Firefox) page https://adsler.co.uk menu

Comment: See how the menu juts out only a bit and bunches together fafa icons and words?

Comment: add this style `.main-navigation .menu > li > ul > li {display: flex; align-items: center;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS for better UX

```
.main-navigation .menu > li ul { padding: 10px; right: 0 !important;}
.main-navigation .menu > li > ul > li { display: flex; align-items: center;}
```

Try to remove this left 0 from here

```
.main-navigation .menu > li ul {  left: 0; }
style.css line #1448
```

[image]

Comment: No Problem mate!